# Bad kerning in some words when printing Word document

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2007

I have the following setup, with everything up to date:

- Windows 8.1 (but it happened in Vista on a previous computer too)
- Microsoft Word 2007 (from Home and Student edition)
- HP Photosmart C4580 printer

I have a very simple document, with nothing fancy except for a field with the current date at the beginning. When I open it and print it, some of the words have some letters smashed together. It seems that it only happens in letters with accents or some special characters:
[image]

At first, I thought it had to do with the font, because I was using the then-new Calibri, but it happens with Arial too.

Also, if I open the file, then change the font, it doesn't happen anymore.

I haven't noticed errors with other programs, but I don't print anything much, but some images.

Any idea what can be causing this?

**UPDATE:** I've tried printing to XPS, and now the document itself looks wrong (but not as wrong as the printed version or the XPS):

[image]

Comment: Does it happen when printing the file as an image, rather than as text? If not, then the issue might be the fonts that the printer is using. Try also printing as PDF, then sending PDF to printer.

Comment: Hmmm... @DrMoishePippik, since I don't have a PDF printer set up, I've tried the "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" and I've found that, not only does it print it wrong, but now the document itself is wrong. Strange, really...

Comment: It is progress, since you've shown the issue is within MS Office or the printer *driver*, not the printer itself. Have you gone to the HP site to download the latest drivers and diagnostic tools, http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Photosmart-C4500-All-in-One-Printer-series/3575173/model/3575174/drivers?

Comment: Since the Microsoft XPS Document Writer shows the problem too, I would bet the printer, or its drivers, don't have anything to do.